# How can I use file names as an input?

Tags: python, pandas, input

I wrote a python script (with pandas library) to create txt files. I also use a txt file as an input. It works well but I want to make it more automated.

My code starts like;

```
girdi = input("Lütfen gir: ")
input2 = girdi+".txt"
veriCNR = pd.read_table(
    input2, decimal=",",
    usecols=[
        "Chromosome",
        "Name",
.
.
.
```

I am entering the name of the files one by one and getting outputs like this:

```
.
.
.    
outputCNR = girdi+".cnr"
sonTabloCNR.to_csv(outputCNR, sep="\t", index=False)

outputCNS = girdi+".cns"
sonTabloCNS.to_csv(outputCNS, sep="\t", index=False)

outputCNG = girdi+".genemetrics.cns"
sonTabloCNG.to_csv(outputCNG, sep="\t", index=False)
```

As you see I am using input name also for outputs. They are tab seperated txt files with different file extensions.

I want to use all txt files in a folder as an input and run this script for every  one of them.

I hope I explained it clearly.

ps. I am not a programmer. Please be explanatory with codes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code creating the files in a function which takes the filepath as input:

```py
def generate_results(input_filepath):
    # your code generating the files
```

then you can use this function in a loop to generate all the result files.

Here's an example using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to get all the text files in `directory`

```py
import os
import glob

directory = "path to my directory"
for filepath in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.txt")):
    generate_results(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the files in folder use
`os.listdir(path)`. It returns list of filenames on path (by default it's current directory).

So for example:

```py
import os

supported_extensions = ['.cns', '.cnr']
for filename in os.listdir():
    # Make sure file has desired extension
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in supported_extensions:
        function(filename)
```